# removing every item from list A if its in list B returns no empty list, even though A == B

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wrote the following python code in jupiter-notebook:

```
x=['b','x','a']
y=['b','x','a']
for i in x:
    if i in y:
        x.remove(i)
print (x)
```

I expected an empty list, but the output was ['x'].
What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this behavior because you are removing items in the list `x` while iterating on it.

To have the result you expect (an empty list), you should use a list comprehension :

```
x = [i for i in x if i not in y]
print(x) # prints []
```

Check this StackOverflow question on the same subject : [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0):

The bug is happening because you are removing an element of the list `x` while you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate. Try this:

```
set(x)-set(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the *filter*-function, as such

`x = list(filter(lambda element: element not in y, x))`

See http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter